# How to replace specific character one time

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace character `-` using regular expression in my text so it would work like this:

Original text:       `abcd-efg-hijk-lmno`
Text after replacing: `abcd-efg-hijk/lmno`

As you can see I want to replace character `-` starting from the end just one time with character `/`.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)-([^-]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1/$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  (.+)      : 1 or more any character, catch in group 1
  -         : a dash
  ([^-]+)   : 1 or more any character but dash, catch in group 2
$           : end of line
```

Answer (score 4):

Find what: `-([^-]*)$`

Replace with: `/$1`

Search Mode: Regular Expression

**Explanation:**

```
-         : a dash
([^-]*$)  : text with no dash, 
            zero or more times, 
            to the end of the line,
            put in the $1 variable
/$1       : literal "/", contents of $1
```

Good resource: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

Answer (score 3):

To replace characters in Notepad++, you can open the Replace window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, or under the "Search" menu. Once open, enter the following regular expression:

```
(.{4}-.{3}-.{4})(-)(.{4})
```

This will find:

- a group of four characters (the "." being any character, the "{4}" being    the quantity),
- a dash,
- a group of three characters,
- another dash,
- a group of four characters,
- again another dash,
- then a group of four characters.

The parentheses group this search into captured groups, which we will use for the replacement part. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more info.

If you want to restrict the search to lowercase letters as in your example, you would replace the "." with "[a-z]", or for upper and lower "[a-z,A-Z]".

Now for the replacement. The groups from earlier are referenced by the dollar sign then the number, e.g. $1 would be the first. So we will replace the characters found with the first group ($1), disregard the second group containing the dash and insert the "/" instead, then include the third group ($3):

```
$1/$3
```

The settings in the replace window need to have "Regular expression" and "Wrap around" checked, and ". matches newline" unchecked.

You can then click <kbd>Replace all</kbd> to replace all occurrences, or go through using <kbd>Replace</kbd> individually.

Since the beginning and end of line characters are not included, you can find multiple occurrences of this pattern on a single line.

Note: This answer follows the same procedure as Toto's, however uses a different regular expression.

Comment: You should anchor your regex, at least at the end. But this will work only for strings that have 3 dashes.

Comment: @Toto I understood that the OP had a pattern of the form "abcd-efg-hijk-lmno" from which the last dash was to be replaced. To me, the statement "starting from the end" meant "of the pattern"). If the data is not in a pattern as I have assumed, and the OP wants the last dash in each line is to be replaced - then your solution is certainly more appropriate (since this mine does not do that).

Comment: @BBXAXX Does the data you are looking to modify contain dashes dispersed randomly throughout, or is there a pattern of 4-3-4-4? (the numbers represent the quantity of characters) if it's a pattern, would there be more than one occurrence on a line?